# Selecting an interface when multicasting on windows

Tags: c++, qt, multicast

I want to send data via a specific network interface

```
udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(QHostAddress(Address),
                              QNetworkInterface::interfaceFromName(iface));
```

but, data is sending via another network interface. How can I force it to send data by that interface?

*It is tested with SmartSniff.*

Comment: I think you might have to look into calling `setsockopt` for the option [IP_MULTICAST_IF](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html)

Comment: @simonc :  i used 'QUdpSocket Class'  , i cant use setsockopt

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [void QUdpSocket::setMulticastInterface(const QNetworkInterface & iface)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qudpsocket.html#setMulticastInterface)?

Comment: @thuga : i used this function , but not working correctly .

Comment: @MeysamHit Can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: @thuga : Problem :  i want to send data over eth0 , but data send over eth1

Comment: @MeysamHit Does `QUdpSocket::multicastInterface()` return the correct interface?

Comment: @thuga : yes udpSocket->multicastInterface().humanReadableName() return true name .

Comment: @MeysamHit `QUdpSocket::setMulticastInterface(const QNetworkInterface & iface)` only works when you bind your socket to an address. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367209/using-qudpsocket-to-send-datagrams) will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining multicast groups is for *receiving.*

If you want your *`send()`* invocations to go on a specific interface you need to `bind()` to it.

Comment: How can I bind my socket to a specific interface and force my packets to go from it? My problem is _sending_.

Comment: With the `bind()` method, as I said.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you show me an example? _I'm trying to send data, but I cant understand how `bind()` will help me to force the program to route data via a specific interface._

Comment: You want to bind to a specific interface, so call `bind()`. Nothing confusing about that. Binding to a specific IP address will force all sends via that socket to be sent via the interface that has that IP address.

Comment: Downvote because bind() only works for receiving under Windows.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @EJP Now I hate myself. 3 weeks ago I was going to start writing a program that sends packets though different interfaces, so started gathering information about this, but I don't know how I got, here, in StackOverflow, that bind() on Windows only works for incoming data, so I connected 2 laptops, one with Windows and the other one with Linux to work on my project (obviously the Linux one is to divide the packets). Now I'm trying to find that info and I only read how to select interface before connecting under Windows... What the h**l have I searched the last time to read that...?

Comment: Ok, I found it here (Chrome history...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows/2080495#2080495 and now reading more I see that that was in Windows OS under Vista version. Now works properly... I guess that I have to read more before taking a decision :-/ EDIT: Vote locked until answer is edited? Well, I guess that you can add that info telling that old OS do not work the normal way.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Edited it. As a general rule, if you disagree with an answer you should provide a reason, and preferable a counter-citation. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says 'The bind function might be used before send operations using the sendto,WSASendMsg, or WSASendTo functions if an application wanted to select a specific local IP address'.